# How to group identical strings in to any collection?

Tags: java

I have a string looks like

```
 {APP,LEE,APP,KCC,KCC,LEE,APP}.
```

I want to push same values like APP, LEE, KCC into different arraylists(any    collection) respectively.

For example:

- arraylist 1 should have {APP,APP,APP}
- arraylist 2 should have {KCC,KCC}
- arraylist 3 should have {LEE,LEE}

So that i can identify how many distinct groups are there and whats their value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you tell a bit further, what would you do with those lists? I feel `Map<String,Integer>` may suit your needs. e..g `{"APP":3,"KCC":2}` however you need tell us, what you want to do with those lists.

Comment: My reqirement is to find distint values from the given string or Arraylist and display the
values only if there are > 10 distinct values. Thanks for all your precise answers. Cowls answer 
served best to my issue. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Map<String, List<String>>`. Each value will contain a list of elements (you can use Integer to count if you want)

When you add an element:

```
List<String> elemList = myMap.get(key);
if (elemList == null){
    elemList = new ArrayList<String>;
    myMap.put(key, elemList);
}
elemList.add(key);
```

Although using counter is better...

```
    Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
...
    Integer count = myMap.get(key);
    if (count == null){
        myMap.put(key, 1);
    } else {
        myMap.put(key, count + 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could instead create a Set from the ArrayList (This would remove duplicates) and then take the size of the set and each item of the set would be one group

```
Set<String> groups = new HashSet<String>(list);

groups.size(); //Number of groups

for(String group : groups) {
    System.out.println(group); //Print each value
}
```

Comment: how can he know there are exact 3 `APP`s and 2 `LEE`s with Set?

Comment: He didnt say that was required: "So that i can identify how many distinct groups are there and whats their value."

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the precise answers.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easiest to create a map with each list.  Then if a key does not exit, create the entry it, then append.

Something like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

String[] values = source.substring(1, source.length() - 1).split(",");
for (String value : values) {
   List<String> existingMatches = result.get(value);
   if (existingMatches == null) {
     existingMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
     result.put(value, existingMatches);
   }
   existingMatches.add(value);
}
```

If you just need a count of the distinct values, replace the List with an AtomicInteger, and increment the value, then you end up with a map of distinct Strings, and a count of the num ber of times it appears.